# bufferedReader.readLine() will never equal null

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I am writing some code that will pull a name and id from a text file. To do this I am using a while loop. It appears that the while loop condition is always true and the program never breaks out of the while loop. The code is shown below Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            endOfFirstName = line.indexOf(",");
            first_name = line.substring(0, endOfFirstName);
            endOfLastName = line.indexOf(" ");
            last_name = line.substring(endOfFirstName + 1, endOfLastName);
            id = line.substring(endOfLastName + 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

Is used to handle a stream ending / being closed -

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

You must handle your own loop termination - depending on what you deem to be loop close worthy.

i.e. In a standard HTTP request, this is done by a blank newline.

*edit*

You are also discarding every other line from your stream

Remove the extra

```
line = br.readLine();
```

As this is already handled by the loop.

Comment: Do you know the condition I should use in order to stop reading once I've gotten to the end of the file?

Comment: Read me edit, try that first. You are throwing away every other line of the file.

Comment: I see. I've added "BREAK" where I want to break out of the loop and set the condition to while(!(br.readLine().equals("BREAK")). However, it still won't break out.

Comment: Edit the original question to reflect any code changes and errors.

Comment: This loop _should_ exit correctly when the file is finished being read.

Comment: No worries. Just be sure to upvote / accept the answers that help! Cheers, and happy coding! :D